# Thingsboard mapping - splitting telemetry data correctly into attributes and timeseries

Tags: attributes, time-series, thingsboard

Whenever I post the telemetry data from sensors ( through thingsboard gateway ), I am also adding the time (unix time as well as datetime in ISO8601 format) to json data. For example

```
{"MAC": "00-14-22-01-23-45","UNIX_TIME": 1519404687,"ISO8601_DATETIME": "2018-
02-23T16:52:38+00:00","VOLTAGE": 3.452}
```

I was just curious - If we were to split the above data into attributes and timeseries, would it be correct ( in a strict sense ) to split it like this

Attributes: **MAC**
Timeseries: **UNIX_TIME**, **ISO8601** and **VOLTAGE**

Or would the UNIX_TIME and ISO8601 go under attributes? Because (logically and technically speaking) they are attributes of the  posted data? I am no expert in deciding that so It would be great to hear from others. I want to use these in the mapping and want to make sure that I start off right. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are attributes for the *device*, not for the posted data.

Attributes are like telemetry values, except that only the last submitted value is stored for attributes, while telemetry data is stored as a time series.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. You mentioned "Attributes are attributes for the device, not for the posted data". Say I have taken a certain reading at a certain time. Now isn't that timestamp an attribute of the posted(recorded) data rather than the device? I mean it has more to do with the actual data and less to do with the device itself? I think you've already answered but I am trying to join the missing bits I have in my head :)

Comment: It depends. If you add an attribute "last update" on the device, and use the timestamp to set that attribute, it becomes an attribute of the device. Thingsboard does not have a concept of "attribute of posted data". Thingsboard only has attribute of device.